# Can you change the location of the pipline log files in Commerce Server 2007?

Tags: logging, commerceserver2007

By default Commerce Server's pipelines log to `%WEBROOT%\pipelines\log`, is there a configuration value that can change this location?

Comment: I havent used this before but the PipelineBase class does have a logPath property (readonly) but which can be set using its contructor. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms967591(v=CS.90).aspx for more information. Are you more concerned about logging for order / CSF pipelines or your own custom ones?

Comment: We want to log for the Order pipelines only, we've got a bug that only occurs very rarely at checkout & I've run out of places to look so I want to see exactly what's happening, but we've got limited space on our server's c: drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this via the Commerce Server 2007 API or configuration.  However, I have achieved this by using the Windows [mklink command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx) to create an [NTFS symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) (supported on Windows Server 2008, Vista and 7).

**How to re-locate the Commerce Server pipeline log using mklink**

1. If the directory `%WEBROOT%\pipelines\log` exists, delete it.
2. Create the new log directory (e.g. `x:\new\location\path`)
3. Run the following command (as admin) to create the symlink:
   `mklink /D %WEBROOT%\pipelines\log x:\new\location\path`
4. Set the appropriate permissions on the new directory (so CS can log to it).
5. Enable CS pipeline logging and watch it log to the new directory.

**Disclaimer:**  I have only used this on a development machine.  I do not know of any reason why it should not work for you in production, but please test and use at your own risk!

**Beware the Dragons:** I'm not sure the pipeline logging gracefully handles concurrent PCF executions (common in prod).  Microsoft also [explicitly advise against enabling pipeline logging in production](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545032%28v=cs.70%29.aspx).